# How to use FB instant articles with ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, rss, facebook-instant-articles

I have a blog made in ruby on rails and it has few articles. Articles are saved in the db. To write the content I use Tinymce gem. The rss was working on Feedly and I would like to show the articles on FB instant articles. I followed the documentation on FB pages:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instant-articles/publishing/setup-rss-feed

and tried to make it work with information found on this two links:
https://www.codingfish.com/blog/129-how-to-create-rss-feed-rails-4-3-steps

and

http://apidock.com/rails/Builder/XmlMarkup

Sometimes FB had loaded the articles but the style was missing, it could not find any content, could not find any articles, then I got the "something went wrong..." error and had to wait for some time and so on.
I do not know what to do. This is the last version of feed.rss.builder and FB can't see nothing (You haven't created any instant articles yet).

```
#encoding: UTF-8
xml.instruct! :xml, :version => "1.0"
xml.rss :version => "2.0" do
  xml.channel do
    xml.title "Blog"
    xml.author "Blog"
    xml.description "Web Development"
    xml.link "http://myblog.dev.eu/"
    xml.language "en"
    for article in @blog_articles
      xml.item do
        if article.title
          xml.title article.title
        else
          xml.title ""
        end
        xml.link("href" => "http://myblog.dev.eu/blog_posts/"+article.slug.to_s)
        xml.guid article.id
        xml.pubDate article.created_at.to_s(:rfc822)
        xml.author article.author_name
        xml.description article.short_description
        xml.html do
          xml.head do                   
            xml.link("rel" => "stylesheet", "title" => "default", "href" => "#")
            xml.title(article.title)
            xml.meta("property" => "fb:article_style", "content" => "bam")
            xml.link("rel" => "canonical", "href" => "http://myblog.dev.eu/blog_posts/"+article.slug.to_s)
          end 
          xml.body do
            xml.header do
              xml.image "http://myblog.dev.eu/" + article.picture_url.to_s
            end
            xml.article(article.content)
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Please help me to fix this code! I would like to submit it for the review and never again touch the code in feed.rss.builder. Thank you!

Edit:

I have changed few things in the code and now it looks so:

```
#encoding: UTF-8
xml.instruct! :xml, :version => "1.0"
xml.rss :version => "2.0", "xmlns:content"=>"http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" do
xml.channel do
  xml.title "MyBlog"
  xml.link "http://myblog/"
  xml.description "Web Development, Digital Marketing, Education"
  xml.language "en-us"
  xml.lastBuildDate Time.new.strftime("%Y-%-m-%dT%H:%M").to_s

  for article in @blog_articles
    xml.item do
      xml.title article.title
      xml.link "http://myblog.eu/"+article.slug.to_s
      xml.guid article.id
      xml.pubDate article.created_at.strftime("%Y-%-m-%dT%H:%M").to_s
      xml.author article.author_name
      xml.description article.short_description
        xml.content:encoded do
          xml.tag!("!doctype html") 
          xml.html("lang"=>"en", "prefix"=>"op:http://media.facebook.com/op#") do
            xml.head do
              xml.meta("charset"=>"utf-8")   
              xml.link("rel" => "stylesheet", "title" => "default", "href" => "#")
              xml.title(article.title)
              xml.link("rel" => "canonical", "href" => "http://myblog.eu/blog_posts/"+article.slug.to_s)
              xml.meta("property" => "fb:article_style", "content" => "bam")
            end 
            xml.body do
              xml.article do 
                xml.header do
                  xml.figure("data-mode" => "aspect-fit") do
                    xml.img("src"=>"http://myblog.eu/blog_posts/#{article.picture.url}")
                  end
                  xml.h1 article.title
                  xml.h2 article.short_description 
                  xml.h3("Introduction" , "class"=>"op-kicker")
                  xml.address "myadr"
                  xml.time(article.created_at.strftime("%B %dth %Y, %l:%M %p").to_s, "class" => "op-published", "dateTime" => article.created_at.strftime("%Y-%-m-%dT%H:%M").to_s) 
                  xml.time(article.created_at.strftime("%B %dth %Y, %l:%M %p").to_s, "class" => "op-modified", "dateTime" => article.updated_at.strftime("%Y-%-m-%dT%H:%M").to_s)
                end

                xml.p article.content
                xml.figure("data-feedback"=>"fb:likes, fb:comments") do
                  xml.img("src"=>"http://myblog.eu/blog_posts/#{article.picture.url}")      
                    xml.figcaption do
                      xml.h1 "descript"
                      xml.cite "text"
                    end                 
                end
                xml.footer do 
                  xml.small "Lab"
                end
              end
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Now FB recognizes articles but still I have the error: "Missing logo". I added the logo in FB styles and it can be found on line:

```
xml.meta("property" => "fb:article_style", "content" => "bam")
```

When I open one article in FB editor the whole content is added in the article tag before header tag. It look's something like this:

```
<html>
<body><article><p>!doctype html/&gt;

...Content...


      </p>
<header><time class="op-modified" datetime="2016-01-19T10:38:00-08:00">2016-01-19T10:38:00-08:00</time><time datetime="2016-01-19T10:38:00-08:00" class="op-published"></time><h1>Title</h1></header><footer></footer></article></body>
<head><link rel="canonical" href="http:///myblog.eu/article.title"></head>
</html>
```

And it's not ready for the review. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Content should be wrapped in a CDATA comments block.

This is how I've done that in Rails.

```
xml.instruct!
xml.rss "version" => "2.0" do
  xml.channel do

    # Required channel elements...
    xml.title "Thinker's Playground"

    xml.link root_url(utm_source: "Feed", utm_medium: "RSS", utm_campaign: "RSS")

    xml.description TAGLINE

    # Optional channel elements...
    xml.language       "en"
    xml.copyright      "Copyright 2008—#{Date.today.year}, Thinker's Playground"
    xml.managingEditor rss_user(User.first)
    xml.webMaster      rss_user(User.first)
    xml.pubDate        @posts.first.updated_at.to_s(:rfc822)
    xml.lastBuildDate  @posts.first.updated_at.to_s(:rfc822)
    xml.category       "Personal growth"
    xml.generator      "Ruby on Rails"
    xml.docs           "https://validator.w3.org/feed/docs/rss2.html"
    xml.ttl            1440
    xml.image do
      xml.title "Thinker's Playground"
      xml.url   "https://thinkersplayground.com/paperplane.png"
      xml.link  root_url(utm_source: "Feed", utm_medium: "RSS", utm_campaign: "RSS")
    end


    # For each post, create an <item> tag...
    @posts.each do |post|
      xml.item do
        # Required item elements...
        xml.title post.title
        # Optional item elements...
        xml.link post_url(post)
        xml.description post.description.to_s.html_safe
        xml.author "#{post.blogger_email} (#{post.blogger_name})"
        xml.category post.category.name
        xml.pubDate post.published_at.to_s(:rfc822)
        xml.source("Thinker's Playground", url: feed_url)
        xml.tag!("content:encoded") do
          xml.cdata!(render(template: "posts/rss/_instant_article_html", formats: "html", locals: { post: post }))
        end
      end
    end
  end
end


# _instant_article_html.html.slim
doctype html
html lang="en" prefix="op: http://media.facebook.com/op#"
  head
    meta property="op:markup_version" content="v1.0"
    meta charset="utf-8"
    link rel="canonical" href== post_url(post)
  body
    article
      header
        = post.title

      = markdown post.content

      footer
        // footer
```